# Motion blur during CABasicAnimation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation, core-graphics

I have this simple animation that moves an image from one point to another:

```
    CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    anim.fromValue  = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(px2.x, px2.y)];
    anim.toValue    = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(P3x, P3y)];
    anim.duration   = 1.5f;
    anim.repeatCount =1;
    anim.removedOnCompletion = YES;
    anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
    [LA  addAnimation:anim forKey:@"positionTest"];
```

The problem is that the image becomes blurry while in motion, the motion is not very fast. 
Is there a way to reduce this motion blur?

Comment: can we see a screenshot? Also are the values for px2.x etc. across pixel boundaries? I.e. do they have fractional parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a screenshot during the animation is it definitely blurred? Also is the blurring a pixellated blur or is it more like a soft gaussian blur?

Try setting view.layer.shouldRasterize = yes and layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen.scale;

Comment: The blur is because of iPad 2 display IPS panel lag. On iPhone device there is no blur.